# Bootstrap Accordion inside Tabs

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-tabs, bootstrap-accordion

I have for sake of example created two tabs (Tab1, Tab2). Under each tab there are accordions. The behavior of accordion inside both tabs is not exactly the same. Under tab1 if I expand an accordion all other accordions collapse automatically, however, for tab2 if i expand an accordion it will not collapse other accordions which is expanded. I need the behavior as in Tab1.

Below is minimal code in HTML and CSS:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.nav li a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#accordionMenu {
  max-width: 750px;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}

.panel-group .panel+.panel {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}

.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e4e5e7;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  float: right;
  transition: transform .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s linear;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\e113";
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
  content: "\e114";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/leaflet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/leaflet-logo.css">


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@4.4.0"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@3.0.0-rc12"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@3.29.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/uikit.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='js/leaflet-logo.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='js/fespoint.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fes.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='js/d3.v5.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='data/data3.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='js/color.js'></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div id="exTab2" style="padding: 40px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
      </li>

    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content ">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
        <div>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordionMenu" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                     MenuA
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">ItemA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                     menu B
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#" id="A1a">ItemA1 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="A1b">Item B2</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    Menu C
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">B1 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B2 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B3 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B4 </a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingsix">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapsesix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsesix">
                     Menu D
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapsesix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingsix">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">A11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">A12</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">A13</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">A2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
        <div>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordionMenu" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading1">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
                     Menu 0
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading2">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                     Menu 1
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading3">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">
                     Menu 2
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading3">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading4">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse4">
                     Menu 3
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading4">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have the ID `accordionMenu` on more than one element. Sidequestion: Why do you use camelCase on IDs but kebap-case on class references? Mixing conventions is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both accordions are using the same `id="accordionMenu"` , make sure each of them have different ids and that this ids are reflected correctly on the `data-parent` attribute of their respective items

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.nav li a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#accordionMenu {
  max-width: 750px;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}

.panel-group .panel+.panel {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}

.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e4e5e7;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  float: right;
  transition: transform .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s linear;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\e113";
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
  content: "\e114";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/leaflet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/leaflet-logo.css">


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@4.4.0"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@3.0.0-rc12"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@3.29.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/uikit.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='js/leaflet-logo.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='js/fespoint.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fes.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='js/d3.v5.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='data/data3.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='js/color.js'></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div id="exTab2" style="padding: 40px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
      </li>

    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content ">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
        <div>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordionMenu" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                     MenuA
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">ItemA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                     menu B
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#" id="A1a">ItemA1 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="A1b">Item B2</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    Menu C
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">B1 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B2 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B3 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B4 </a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingsix">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu" href="#collapsesix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsesix">
                     Menu D
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapsesix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingsix">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">A11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">A12</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">A13</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">A2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
        <div>
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordionMenu2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading1">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu2" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
                     Menu 0
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading2">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu2" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
                     Menu 1
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading2">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading3">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu2" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">
                     Menu 2
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading3">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading4">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMenu2" href="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse4">
                     Menu 3
                   </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading4">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```